# Increasing function $f(x,y,y)=f(x,x,y)$ implies $f(x,y,z)=g(x,z)$?

Tags: contest-math, recreational-mathematics, functional-equations, functional-inequalities

Got a super super interesting contest problem. $f(x,y,z)$ is a continuous function of three variables; it is required that $x\leq y\leq z$ (this means that $f$ is only defined on the 3-tuples such that $x\leq y\leq z$).

$f$ is increasing in the sense that $x'>x, y'>y,$ and $z'>z$ implies $f(x',y',z')>f(x,y,z)$.

Is it true that:

$$f(x,y,y)=f(x,x,y) \iff f(x,y,z)=g(x,z)?$$

A friend made this problem for practice purposes and I guess it could be a little bit loosely defined but the idea is there!

My try:

The statement is false and here is a counterexample. Let $A$ be a set; define the "secondary minimal function": $\min_2(A)=\{a\in A||a\leq A\setminus  \min A; \}$ if nonempty; and if empty then $\min_2 A=0$.

**Let** $f(x,y,z)=\min\{x,y,z\}+\min_2\{x,y,z\}$.

for example: $f(0,0,1)=0+1=f(0,1,1)$ but $f(1,2,3)=1+2\neq g(1,3)$

My solution is too complicated. Is there a simple solution/counterexample?

Comment: If $f$ is monotonic in $y$ for each fixed $x,z,$ it is true that $g(x,z)=f(x,x,z)$ works. But that is sort of obvious. Perhaps you want a linear $f?$

Comment: Why is your solution "too complicated?" It's a fine solution, if you mean $f(x,y,z)=x+z$ if $x=y,$ otherwise $x+y.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You are right I forgot about the monotonicity condition. Do you mean that with monotonicity we can get $f(x,y,z)=g(x,z)$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes your last comment is what I meant

Comment: Well, if you forgot the monotonic requirement, put it in your question. Don't leave your question incomplete and ask people to answer a different question in comments.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks, I edited the question. Shall I reopen a new question? I am very interested your comment that if monotonicity (specified in the edited problem) holds then the result is correct.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Both your and OP's examples (which only differ by the fact that $f(x,y,z) = 0$ if $x = y = z$ for OP) fail to respect the monotonicity property in (at least) this edge case: $\begin{cases} z' > z \geq 2y' \\ y' > x' > x = y \\ x' - x \leq y' \end{cases}$. In that case, we have: $f(x',y',z') = x' + y'$ and $f(x,y,z) = x + z \geq x + 2y' \geq x + (x' - x) + y' = x' + y'$, therefore $f(x,y,z) \geq f(x',y',z')$ yet $x' > x$, $y' > y$ and $z' > z$.

Comment: (I included "$x' - x \leq y'$" but I realise it's already implied by $x' < y'$, and I can't edit my comment due to the 5 minute time limit)

Comment: @BrunoB Those comments were written before the question contained monotonicity.

Answer (score 2):

By continuity of $f$ on $S := \left\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x \leq y \leq z\right\}$ and the monotonicity condition, we have $f(x,y,z) \leq f(x',y',z')$ for all $\big((x,y,z), (x',y',z')\big) \in S^2$ such that $x \leq x'$, $y \leq y'$ and $z \leq z'$.

Let $x \leq z$ be fixed, let $y \in [x,z]$.
Then we have:
$$f(x,z,z) = f(x,x,z) \leq f(x,y,z) \leq f(x,z,z)$$
As such: $$\forall y \in [x,z],\quad f(x,y,z) = f(x,z,z)$$
Therefore, $f$ is indeed only a function of $x$ and $z$.